# Orientation for sub items in a horizontally oriented menu in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to figure out the best way to orient sub menu items vertically in a ASP Menu which is oriented horizontally like this

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal">
         <Items>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Home" Value="Home" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Home.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx" Text="Artist" Value="Artist">
                                 <asp:MenuItem Text="A" Value="A" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/A"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="B" Value="B" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/B"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="C" Value="C" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/C"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="D" Value="D" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/D"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="E" Value="E" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/E"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="F" Value="F" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/F"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="G" Value="G" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/G"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="H" Value="H" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/H"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="I" Value="I" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/I"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="J" Value="J" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/J"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="K" Value="K" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/K"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="L" Value="L" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/L"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="M" Value="M" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/M"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="N" Value="N" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/N"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="O" Value="O" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/N"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="P" Value="P" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/P"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Q" Value="Q" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/Q"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="R" Value="R" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/R"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="S" Value="S" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/S"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="T" Value="T" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/T"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="U" Value="U" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/U"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="V" Value="V" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/V"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="W" Value="W" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/W"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="X" Value="X" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/X"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Y" Value="Y" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/Y"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Z" Value="Z" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/Z"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="0-9" Value="0-9" NavigateUrl="~/Music/Artist.aspx/0-9"></asp:MenuItem>
                            </asp:MenuItem>
```

I want the menu to appear like this on mouse over Artist

Can anyone suggest some solution trying to avoid CSS and Javascript?

At the moment the ABCs appear like this
A

B

C

D

E

I want them to appear like a bar

A B C D E .............

Update: 
I want the sub menu to appear on hover like a dropdownlist only condition is that the list needs to be a horizontal row rather than a vertical column.

Answer (score 0):

can you clarify? the items appear as a bar, just as your example at the bottom; do you want something like a hover popup menu? in which case, the ajax one is an easy choice http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HoverMenu/HoverMenu.aspx

Comment: I need a hover menu like the one in your link. But in this example on hovering "Edit" and "Delete" appear vertically. I want them to appear horizontally side by side.